# Netsuite Saved Search Criteria Formula

Tags: oracle, formula, netsuite, saved-searches

I am trying to filter my criteria based on 4 custom fields. How can I write the correct formula text in criteria?
{custitem_field1} and or {custitem_field2}and or{custitem_field3}and or{custitem_field4}

[image: SS criteria formula]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach would be to expand it into a CASE statement - something like this:

```
CASE WHEN {custom_field1} = 'T' OR {custom_field2} = 'T' OR {custom_field3} = 'T' OR {custom_field4} = 'T' THEN '1' ELSE '0' END
```

and set the operator below to `is` and the value to `1`.

There is probably a better way, but this is simple, works, and is the first solution that comes to mind.